# What kind of feeling does this 烦恼 describes?

Tags: meaning, difference

What's the difference beetwen 烦恼，担心，着急，难过，生气？

Answer (score 1):

烦恼 - troubled (e.g. 為錢烦恼 = troubled by money problem) *烦恼 about something that is happening*

担心 - worry (e.g. 担心不夠錢發工資 = Worried about not having enough money to pay wages) *担心 about something that will or might happen*

着急 - anxious/ urgent (着急找工作 = anxiously/urgently looking for a job) *着急 about something that's not happening fast enough*

难过 - sad/ feel bad; *You can feel bad for many things and for other people*

生气 - angry, *You can be angry at many different things or people*